# Problem checking number of decimal places in excel via COM-Object

Tags: excel, openedge, progress-4gl, comobject

I am writing a program with OpenEdge Progress 11.7, which is to validate an Excel file provided by internal users. One of the things that I need to validate is the number of digits that the decimal numbers have on the spreadsheet. On the Excel, the decimal numbers are displayed with 4 decimal places. However, if I invoke the LENGTH function in Progress to Read the decimal numbers, it returns me the integer that show the decimal numbers have more than 4 decimal places(please refer to the below screenshots). Is there any workaround that I might adopt? Please accept my gratitude for any advice.

Pseudo Code:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE chExcel AS COM-HANDLE.
DEFINE VARIABLE chWB AS COM-HANDLE.
DEFINE VARIABLE chWS AS COM-HANDLE.
DEFINE VARIABLE cInFinFile AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

cInFinFile = "N:\test.xlsx".

/* create excel instance */
CREATE "Excel.Application" chExcel.
ASSIGN
    chExcel:Visible = TRUE
    chExcel:screenupdating = TRUE
    chExcel:displayAlerts = FALSE
    chWB = chExcel:Workbooks:OPEN(cInFinFile).
    
MESSAGE chExcel:Range("C5"):VALUE SKIP LENGTH(chExcel:Range("C5"):VALUE) VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
    
chWB:CLOSE.
RELEASE OBJECT chWB NO-ERROR.
chExcel:QUIT().
RELEASE OBJECT chExcel NO-ERROR.
```

[Value on Excel:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57KSh.png)

[Value get in Progress:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di4pG.png)

I try to invoke the Excel com-handle RUN to call the "LEN" function instead to check the length, but the return does not look good

Comment: In Excel the numbers are stored in one of the native types. What you see on the screen is only the actually displayed formatted content, but the number is the same.

Comment: Dear Black cart, thank you very much for your reply and really appreciate it. However, when I use the Visual Basic Immediate Window to debug the value, it is giving the value "1.43" instead of "1.4299...". And I have another cell, which is liked what you say, the displayed value in the cell, which is formatted, is 0.9829 but its actual value is 0.982866666666667. And if I use the immediate window to debug,  it gives me "0.982866666666667", so I think the issue that I reported might not solely due to the excel formatting problem

Comment: Dear Black cat, good day, I used the Range("celladdr").Value method to display the message and I obtained "1.43". And The fellows in the progress community suggested that there can be problems in value precision between excel and ABL. Hence, I have switched the approach to convert the Excel to CSV first, and further process with the CSV. Thanks for your reply, wish you a good day.